# Edit text is not getting updated in Focus change Listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to update edit text from focus change listener but it unable to update. Log is getting called but edit text is not getting called.

**Contact_Fragment(Fragment)**

```
     toET.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if (!hasFocus) {

              Log.d("Focus", hasFocus + "");

              if (v.getId() == R.id.eTto) {
                 if (toET.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                   && (!toET.getText().toString().endsWith(","))) {

                     Log.d("Append", "true");

                     toET.append(",");
                   }

                 }
            });
```

Comment: Downvoter plz specify the reason

Comment: are u getting data in `Log.d("Data", cList.toString());` line?

Comment: Yes i am getting data on the line

Answer (score 0):

It's a terrible example. Fragments should use activity as mediator, for passing data between each other. Great example by link: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fragments/EU4You_6

Comment: This `toET.setText(cList.toString());` not getting called

Comment: Maybe you have a few TextView which have same id (e.g TextView1).